# Show a list of users that logged in exactly 5 days ago from today in linux?

Tags: linux, awk

The `last` command displays the history of login attempts. How to filter the output so that it displays the users logged in from 5 days before current date?

Here is what I've been able to do so far:

```
last | grep Dec | grep -v reboot | awk '{print$5}'
```

This parses the dates from the output of last command.

```
#!/bin/bash
     count=`$date "+%d"`
     count=$((count-5))
     last|grep -v reboot|grep Dec|awk '($5>=$count) {print $0}'
```

worked for me :) Thanks for the help @Olivier Dulac

Comment: Post some code you've tried, this helps people help you.

Comment: @Paul 
      last|grep Dec|grep -v reboot|awk '{print$5}' This command searches for the log entries in December and parses the date

Comment: See, @NaveenV, someone else edited your question for you to include what you tried.  If you click "edit" and add the output and why you did not like it or what you wanted instead, then you will have a fairly complete question.

Comment: @Paul thanks for conveying it..will do that

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't do it in one line, but here's a little bash script which might get the job done:

```
#! /bin/bash

# Find the date string we want
x=$(date --date="5 days ago" +"%a %b %e");

# And now chain a heap of commands together to...
#   1. Get the list of user
#   2. Ignore reboot
#   3. Filter the date lines we want
#   4. Print the user name using awk
#   5+6. Sort them and extract the unique values
last | grep -v "reboot" | grep "$x" | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

in your awk (I don't have "last" here so I can't know the format)
just add a condition to only print the whole line when you see what you want:

ex: if the month is the 3rd field, and day is the 4th field,

```
last | grep -v reboot | awk ' ( ($3 == "Dec") && ($4 == "07") ) { print $0 ; }'
```

(once again, without an actual excerpt of "last", I can't tell if the above works, but I hope you get the general idea)

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. I will try it. Can i include conditional operator like >= <= to check conditions in awk?

Comment: @NaveenV: yes, many operators will work. You can google for "awk manual" and see lots of (free) informations about awk (usually about gawk, a recent version of awk, and the one you have if you are using linux or mac. If you work on older systems, you need to focus on awk-only solutions, so some things will not work)

Answer (score 0):

I think `chooban`'s solution is the closest, but it lists only the matching lines. I found a better solution, and most probably it handles the 2013-12-31 - 2014-01-01 issue properly (I found no trace of the output format if a user is logged in more the one year..., or the login time is in the previous year). It is a [grep](/questions/tagged/grep)-less one (long)liner:

```
last | awk -v l="$(last -t $(date -d '-5 day' +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)|head -n 1)" 'BEGIN {l=substr(l,1,55)} /^reboot / {next} substr($0,1,55) == l  {exit} 1
```

I assumed that there is no such user as 'reboot'. It uses the fact that `last -t YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` prints the lines before the specific date, but unfortunately it changes the format if the logout is inside the specified period (shows "gone - no logout"), so it has to be cut off.

This is not the nicest as it calls last twice, but it seems working.

Output:

```
root     pts/1        mytst.xyzzy.tv   Wed Dec 11 12:45   still logged in   
root     pts/0        mytst.xyzzy.tv   Wed Dec 11 11:25   still logged in   
root     pts/0        mytst.xyzzy.tv   Tue Dec 10 16:02 - 17:14  (01:12)    
root     pts/0        mytst.xyzzy.tv   Tue Dec 10 10:59 - 15:04  (04:05)    
root     pts/0        mytst.xyzzy.tv   Mon Dec  9 13:23 - 17:10  (03:46)    
root     pts/1        mytst.xyzzy.tv   Fri Dec  6 16:01 - 16:07  (00:06)    
root     pts/0        mytst.xyzzy.tv   Fri Dec  6 15:52 - 16:08  (00:15)
```

I hope this could help!